# Homebrew: How to check if a homebrew service is switched on or not

Tags: bash, shell, elasticsearch, curl, homebrew

I am using `elasticsearch` instance as a nosql database. This was installed with `brew` on mac os.

This is how I start `elasticsearch`.

```
brew services start elasticsearch
```

I was wondering if there is a brew command (or other) where I can know if an `elasticsearch` instance is on or not.

Ultimately I want to run a **bash script** that does the following:

```
If elasticsearch is off:
    Turn on elastiscearch
    Proceed
Else:
    Proceed
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`brew services list` gives the **status** of the **services**. so something like `brew services list | grep elastiscearch | awk '{ print $2}'` should return the status of the elastic search service, whether **started** or **stopped**

Answer (score 5):

Just run:

```
brew services
```

**Sample Output**

```
Name      Status  User Plist
grafana   started mark /Users/mark/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.grafana.plist
influxdb  started mark /Users/mark/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.influxdb.plist
mosquitto stopped      
redis     started mark /Users/mark/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
unbound   stopped
```

You can also run the following command to get the process id (pid) of the **homebrew** services:

```
launchctl list | grep homebrew

460 0   homebrew.mxcl.influxdb
484 0   homebrew.mxcl.grafana
469 0   homebrew.mxcl.redis
```